# Mavericks: how to show monitor display in toolbar?

Tags: mac, toolbar

In Mavericks, I can't find a way to have the Monitor Display options show in the Toolbar, as I could in OS X 10.7.  I like to be able to adjust the brightness, and mirror windows, directly from the toolbar.  Does anyone know how to make this work?  (I'm on a MacBook Air.)

Comment: I know that it still gives the mirroring options when they are available.

Answer (score 1):

Get this tool - it's free, and works great - it also solves some other problems, like identifying external monitors correctly.  Put it in your login items.  A little icon will display in your top right menu bar - everything just works from there.

http://displaymenu.milchimgemuesefach.de

Comment: Thank you!  This is just what I was looking for!  This is terrific!